# Fortify 4.2 SSC Error Processing

Tags: fortify

I’m using **fortify 4.2** (SCA version: 6.2). I’m having hard time to upload an fpr file to the SSC. I always get “Error Processing” and I cannot tell what the problem is. I’ve opened the fpr file with auditworkbench and checked the Certification: it is valid.
 Furthermore, I have a plenty of Scan errors and the majority is labeled with error code 1103 with the following description: Translator execution failed. Translator returned status 139.
Any leads?
PS: I’m scanning a large application which includes different modules written in C, C++ and JAVA.

Comment: There's a lot that could be going wrong here. Check in the ssc.log file in the app server to see if there's a more detailed error. What database are you using with SSC?

Comment: I am confused, when you open the FPR in Audit Workbench and you have plenty of Scan Errors, are you talking about findings under the issues or (sounds more like) these are showing up under Project Summary -> Analysis Information -> Warnings?  How are you scanning the different modules? Is the C/C++ using a make file and you are doing touchless around that?  Can you get a clean scan around the C/C++ file?

Comment: @Eric After looking at the ssc.log file on the server, it seems that the error is related to a duplicate fiile. There are two files: **myFile.h** and **myFile.H** which are different, but Fortify assumes that they are the same file.

Comment: @SBurris I'm scanning the application using a makefile with touchless. After that, i run SCA with -make-mobile then -export-build-session. I send the fbs file using ssh to the scan server to run sourceanalyzer -scan.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment about the two files:

- myFile.h
- myFile.H

I am suspecting that the database in the back-end of SSC is case-insensitive?

Starting with Fortify 4.30 (or possibly 4.40) SSC started enforcing that database collation be case-sensitive (before this time it was stated it should be but was not enforced).

You need to upgrade the version of Fortify that you are using to one of the newer versions (current latest is 16.10).  The SSC install documentation will contain instructions on migrating your SSC database from case-insensitive to case-sensitive.

Comment: Since i did not deploy the current **SSC**, how can i check the running version? It is dployed on Tomcat 6.

Comment: When you are signed into SSC, click on the 'About' in the top right.  This should* be the same version as your Fortify version 4.2.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 139 error usually means that you are using a newer version of C/C++ than Fortify supports.  Currently we are using C++14 or higher and getting the error with 19.2.